# HTTP POST to AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, postman, aws-iot

I want to connect a HTTP device to IoT core.

I have tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#http) with the curl command all goes well.

Now I want to try to use POST with [signatyure version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html)

I'm using postmand to send a POST request, but I got this output:

```
"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.",
```

In authorization fields I have chosen "AWS Signature" and I have completed all of them: access and secret key, aws region and service name=iotdata

I want to get the same results as when I use the curl command:

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --cacert YY.pem --cert XX.pem.crt --key ZZ.pem.key -X POST -d "{ \"Trama\": \"message\"}" "https://PPPPPP.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8443/topics/topicname?qos=1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that both of your commands are a little different, because of the various ways you can send data to AWS IoT.

In the `curl` command you're actually using x.509 certificate approach (you can see here for further information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html) This doesn't need the payload to be signed, it's already trusted because the certificate is.

This approach is mostly unique to AWS IoT, because the aim is that the data comes from lots of devices- and you wouldn't want to give them all an IAM Role. In fact, certificate is the recommended way to send data from a device.

You *can* use these certificates with Postman if you want, by adding them to the request under certificates tab (you only need the `.crt` and `.key` files). See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates for more detailed instructions.

You still can use AWS v4 signatures (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iam-users-groups-roles.html) so the suggestion is that you're not forming the request properly.

Looking at this documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_Publish.html) you should be using:

**Method**: `POST`

**Uri**: `<AWS IoT Endpoint>/<url_encoded_topic_name>?qos=1` (e.g. `https://a1pn10j0v8htvw.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8443/topics/iotbutton/virtualButton?qos=1`)

**Authorisation Type**: AWS Signature

**AccessKey** / **SecretKey**: As per your credentials

**AWS Region**: Region you AWS IoT instances is in

**Service Name**: `iotdata`

**Session Token**: Leave blank

Comment: Thanks for your reply, finally I got the solution trying all kind of combination with Uri and host. Uri is like you said and host is only <AWS IoT Endpoint>. Now the question is, It would be possible to do this with GET? Can I send a message to an IoT device using GET from the POST parameters?

Comment: you have to `POST` to update the device (`GET` would be a weird verb to make changes), but you _can_ get the status of anything published to the shadow using: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_GetThingShadow.html`. Notw that you can't `GET` messages on just any topic, because that's not how the broker works- you have to listen on the websocket.